# Linear Approximation of a function at point a with change of x

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So I know this problem is supposed to be very basic, but I cannot for the life of me get the answer my teacher and book gets. I would very much appreciate if a solution could be posted on how this problem would be solved. Eq.(1) is: $\Delta f = f'(a)\Delta x$ 
Everytime I use the formula I get the $\Delta$f ≈ 0.5

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calculate $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}}$, $f'(3)=\frac{1}{2\cdot 2}=\frac{1}{4}$ and use the formula
$$
\Delta f=f'(3)\cdot 0.2=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{2}{10}=\frac{1}{20}=0.05.
$$

P.S. It looks like you lost one decimal zero.

Comment: Also, note the error expressed as a percentage is approx. $\frac{61}{4939} \approx 0. 0123506$ which is $12.4$% to 3 significant figures.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is more or less the exact value. The calculation is $\Delta f=f(3.2)-f(3)\approx0.049390...$

The linear approximation is $\Delta f\approx f'(3)\cdot 0.2=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1+3}}\cdot 0.2=0.05$.

The results are close. Maybe you have a typo at your approximation result.